# Updating python dictionary in a loop

Tags: python

I have a list of dictionaries `x` and a list of random numbers `x_randoms`. I want to update each of the dictionaries with the values from the list of random numbers. I've done the following and it works, but it feels a bit strange:

```
import random

x = [{'key1': '123', 'key2': {'key2.1': 500, 'key2.2': True}},
     {'key1': '123', 'key2': {'key2.1': 500, 'key2.2': True}},
     {'key1': '123', 'key2': {'key2.1': 500, 'key2.2': True}}]

x_randoms = [random.random() for i in range(len(x))]

print("\nBefore loop...", x)
[j.update({'key3': x_randoms[i]}) for i, j in enumerate(x)]
print("\nAfter loop...", x)
```

The list comp at the bottom is mostly what is bothering me. Is that ok, or can it be improved?

Comment: This is too hypothetical to be on-topic, unfortunately.

Comment: If you're not using the result of a list comprehension, it's a huge clue that there's a far clearer way to write your program. In this case, you should be using an imperative-style `for` loop instead.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Your suspicions are correct, this is called using comprehension syntax for side-effects, and is normally bad practice.

A better way to do this is with a `for` loop

```py
for item in x:
    # this also gets rid of your random number list
    item['key3'] = random.random()
```

Answer (score 3):

Instead of iterating over `range(len(x))` and ignoring the value, you can simply iterate over `x` and ignore the value:

```
x_randoms = [random.random() for _ in x]
```

Instead of enumerating `x` only to access `x_randoms`, you can use `zip` to iterate over both in parallel:

```
for xdic, xr in zip(x, x_randoms):
    xdic['key3'] = xr
```